# Airdrop Contract with Merkletree for Addresses

Tags: erc-20, tokens

I am trying to create a simple airdrop contract that handles a batch transfer of ERC20 tokens from one address to a list of address in a merkletree.

I am struggling to figure out whether or not the function I have below is correct, because everything seems to make sense but it doesn't actually perform any airdrop on test-nets. If someone is able to help me figure out what exactly I am doing wrong, or need to add or change, that would be amazing.

Here is the contract I am working on:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol";

contract BuddyDrop {

    event AirdropCoins(address indexed from, bytes32[] to, uint256[] amount);
    event AirdropNFTs(address indexed from, bytes32[] to, uint256[] tokenId);

    // TRANSFER FUNCTIONS
    /**
     * @dev Batch transfer ERC20 tokens to a list of recipients.
     * @param token Address of the ERC20 contract.
     * @param merkleRoot Merkle root of the merkle tree containing the list of addresses.
     * @param merkleProof Proof of inclusion for each address in the merkle tree.
     * @param amount Amount of tokens to transfer to each recipient.
     * NOTE Merkle tree needs to be generated off-chain to save gas.
     */
    function batchTransferERC20(
        IERC20 token,
        bytes32 merkleRoot,
        bytes32[] calldata merkleProof,
        uint256[] memory amount
    ) external {
        // Cache length and total amount for gas savings
        uint256 recipientsLength = merkleProof.length;
        uint256 totalAmount = recipientsLength * amount[0];

        // Check that balance is sufficient
        require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= totalAmount, "Not enough balance");
        
        // Check that the lengths are the same
        require(recipientsLength == amount.length, "Different lengths");

        // Loop through each address in the merkle proof, verify the address 
        // and transfer the tokens
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipientsLength; i++) {
            bytes32 merkleLeaf = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(merkleProof[i]));
            require(MerkleProof.verify(merkleProof, merkleRoot, merkleLeaf), "Invalid proof");
            token.transfer(toAddress(merkleProof[i]), amount[i]);
        }
        // Emit event
        emit AirdropCoins(msg.sender, merkleProof, amount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Convert bytes32 to address.
     */
    function toAddress(bytes32 addr) internal pure returns (address) {
        return address(uint160(uint256(addr)));
    }

}
```

Based on what I wrote, I am passing in a merkle root, an array of addresses for the merkle proof, the ERC20 token address and the amount for each address within that array of addresses.

I am requiring that the balance of the sender to be enough to handle the total amount, and that each one in the array gets a token.

It then executes the for loop that checks if each address is verifiable in the merkle tree and then executes the OpenZeppelin `transfer` function to send to the specific address and the amount.

Is this the proper way to do this type of airdrop or am I missing some steps?